# testing issue in redux saga method using jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, redux-saga, immutable.js

I am testing my redux saga method using jest. I am facing some issues. Attaching the saga method, test case & the console response.

Let me know where I missed it. Tried lots of googling. But couldn’t find any solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks!

```
/* saga method starts*/
export function* fetchStripeLocations() {
    console.log('saga fetchStripeLocations called:');
    try {
        const BE = yield select((state) => state.BE);
        const PaymentRequestFormReducer = yield select(state => state.PaymentRequestFormReducer.toJS());
        const { stripeLocationsMap } = PaymentRequestFormReducer;
        const paymentsEnabled = isPaymentsEnabled(BE);

        if (!stripeLocationsMap.data && !stripeLocationsMap.isLoading && paymentsEnabled) {
            yield put(actionCreator.fetchingStripeLocations());
            const url = actionCreator.URL.FETCH_STRIPE_LOCATIONS;
            const response = yield call(beAPIResource.get, url, {}, { topLoader: false, isPrimaryAPI: false, cancellable: false });
            const { qcrEnabled, stripeLocationsMap } = response.data;
            yield put(actionCreator.setStripeLocations({ qcrEnabled, stripeLocationsMap }));
        }
    } catch (e) {
        yield put(actionCreator.setStripeLocations({ stripeLocationsMap: {} }));
        yield put(dataFetchingError(e, "Something went wrong please try again later"));
    }
}
/* saga method ends*/

/* test case starts*/
import { testData } from "./TestReducerData";
import { commonTestData } from "../../../../../../__test__/commonTestData";

test('fetchStripeLocations testing should pass', async () => {
    const dispatchedActions = [];
    const stripeDummyData = iMap({
        isLoading: false,
        data: null,
        qcrEnabled: false
    });

    const mockData = { 
        qcrEnabled : false, 
        stripeLocationsMap: {
            isLoading: false,
            data: null,
            qcrEnabled: false
        }
    };

    const mRequest = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(mockData));
    const mockState = {
        BE: commonTestData,
        PaymentRequestFormReducer: testData.initialState
    };
    await runSaga({
            dispatch: (action) => dispatchedActions.push(action),
            getState: () => mockState,
        }, PaymentRequestFormSaga.fetchStripeLocations).done;
    console.log('dispatchedActions', dispatchedActions);
    console.log('mRequest.mock:', mRequest.mock);
    expect(mRequest.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);

    expect(dispatchedActions).toEqual([ActionCreator.setStripeLocations(mockData)]);
});
/* test case ends*/
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Show the code of the saga.

Answer (score 0):

`toBe` is like a reference check, but of course these two objects are not the same instance. `toBe` is rarely the right choice for *objects*

> Use .toBe to compare primitive values or to check referential identity
> of object instances. It calls Object.is to compare values, which is
> even better for testing than === strict equality operator.

You can add [`jest-immutable-matchers`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-immutable-matchers) to your project to compare immutable-js objects for *value equality*:

```
import * as matchers from 'jest-immutable-matchers';

describe('My suite', function () {
  beforeEach(function () {
    expect.extend(matchers);
  });

  it('passes if the immutable objects are equal', function () {
    expect(Immutable.Map({a: 1})).toEqualImmutable(Immutable.Map({a: 1}));
  });
});
```

If you want to test equality of two immutable objects yourself, use `Immutable.is`,
e.g. `Immutable.is(Immutable.Map({a: 1}), Immutable.Map({a: 1}))`